# Dynamically textarea with TinyMce editor

Tags: wysiwyg

I need to used TextArea with Wysiwyg editor. 
That works when textarea is write on page ( Not dynamic , static ).. but my problem is for dynamically textarea.

My code :

```
add_action('admin_head', 'load_tiny_mce');
  function load_tiny_mce() {
     // The 'mode' and 'editor_selector' options are for adding
      // TinyMCE to any textarea with class="tinymce-textarea"
      wp_tiny_mce(true, array(
          'mode' => 'specific_textareas',
         'editor_selector' => 'tinymce-textarea'
     ));
 }
```

I added textarea with javascript code when i push a button.
textareas is basic not with wysiwyg editor ... ! I think i need to bind function ... but how to !

I hope, you understand me .. !

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function to you JavaScript:

```
function textarea_to_tinymce(id){
    if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" && typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
    }
}
```

then when you create the textarea dynamically call it and pass the textarea's id to it.

Just make sure TinyMCE is loaded on that page before or it won't work.

Comment: I added that following code :
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function textarea_to_tinymce(textarea_id){
    if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" && typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
        alert(textarea_id);
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false,textarea_id);
    }
}`
Alert display my textarea's id but that doesn't works :(

Answer (score 0):

any reply button on the comments is automated like :

```
<a class="comment-reply-link"
href="/post_url/?replytocom=187#respond"
onclick="addComment.moveForm("comment-" + id , id , "respond",
response) >Beantwoorden</a
```

>

as far as i have found now, you can not change the onclick event to some function in where you could add this execCommand.

Maybe this page helps you:

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_reply_link
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?