# Append wp_editor to Dynamically created textarea

Tags: plugin-development, wp-editor

So...the same question was asked 9 years ago: [Dynamically textarea with TinyMce editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34596/dynamically-textarea-with-tinymce-editor)
and I dont see a good answer and we now have the wp.editor API. Ive tried a few things, but cant add a WSYWIG editor to a dynamically created textarea. The issue is that the ID needs to be on the page before the  wp.editor.initialize function can work and replace the textarea. I can provide code, but thought maybe someone will just tell me if this can or cant be done.